# Why change slice length in range, value not affected？

Tags: go

```
func main() {
    a1 := []int{0, 1, 2, 3}

    for i, v := range a1 {
        fmt.Println(i, v)

        if i == 0 {
            a1 = a1[2:]
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(a1)
}
```

Real output:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
[2 3]
```

I think a1 has changed when i == 0, so why does v still output the value of original a1？I know the number of iterations in range has been determined, but I'm still confused about this result

Comment: You iterate over the original value of `a1`, assigning a new value to the variable does not change that.

Answer (score 2):

From the language specification on [**For statements with range clause**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range):

> The range expression x *is evaluated **once** before beginning the loop*,
>   with one exception: if at most one iteration variable is present and
>   len(x) is constant, the range expression is not evaluated.