# How can I filter an array from a array of arrays where all the items in one array matches some of the items in another array?

Tags: go

#### TL/DR

How can I filter an array of arrays in go against an array of strings?

Is there a `some` or `any` equivalent of JS/Py in go where I can filter an array of arrays if some or all the items in an array is present in another array?

So for example, consider this as the source array:

```golang
arrays := [][]string{
        {"some", "value"},
        {"some", "value", "another"},
        {"value", "another", "test"},
        {"value", "test"},
        {"some", "test"},
    }
```

And I want to filter `arrays` by `[]string{"some", "value"}` if all the items here are found in the array.

The expected output is

```
[[some value] [some value another]]
```

Altervatively, if I change my filter to `[]string{"some", "test"}`, the expected value is `[[some test]]`

I can get the logic down quite right in my test code

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func inArray(s string, arr []string) bool {
    for _, a := range arr {
        if s == a {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    arrays := [][]string{
        {"some", "value"},
        {"some", "value", "another"},
        {"value", "another", "test"},
        {"value", "test"},
        {"some", "test"},
    }
    filterBy := []string{"some", "value"}
    hold := make([][]string, 0)
    // Ignore this because it doesnt work as expected
    for _, arr := range arrays {
        for _, f := range filterBy {
            if ok := inArray(f, arr); ok {
                hold = append(hold, arr)
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(hold)
}
```

Comment: Do any of these help you answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61641558/golang-append-issue-inside-a-for-loop, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185511/range-references-instead-values, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618103/why-change-slice-length-in-range-value-not-affected, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945030/change-values-while-iterating, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48826460/using-pointers-in-a-for-loop

Comment: Hmm... Not entirely. I can see most of these posts are referencing pointers in for loops, or how range works, but doesnt really help me get to where I am trying to get to.

Comment: You're doing the exact same thing as all those questions by reusing `arr` in each iteration. The overall logic problem are a different matter

Comment: My apologies. Very new to go, and I dont fully understand your cryptic comments. I guess I can try to re write this where it will return an array of booleans per filter item, and then try to get a boolean value from that array of booleans to replicate a `some` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in the `inArray` function is correct for checking whether a single needle `s string` is in a haystack `arr []string`. If you want to extend that to check if *all* of the needles `ss []string` are present in a haystack `arr []string`, then you at least need to loop over the needles as well. Here is an example:

```
func allInArray(ss []string, arr []string) bool {
    for _, s := range ss {
        if !inArray(s, arr) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

[Here is a working example in the playgound.](https://play.golang.org/p/N7q7mE9eDVO)

For course, this is pretty inefficient because it loops over the haystack `arr` as many times as there are needles in `ss`. To make this more efficient, you could pre-process the haystack, turning it into a `map[string]struct{}`, then check the needles against the keys of the map like so:

```
func allInArray(ss []string, arr []string) bool {
    present := make(map[string]struct{})
    for _, a := range arr {
        present[a] = struct{}{}
    }
    for _, s := range ss {
        if _, ok := present[s]; !ok {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

[Here is a working example in the playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/5GS-6cKGTFP)

This iterates over `arr` once to create the lookup map, then iterates over `ss` once, taking advantage of the constant lookup time of the map to check whether or not an element of `ss` is present in `arr`.

Comment: Creating map for every array is an inefficient solution rather create map of filter array is more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Check for all filter string of array found in each array then decides to append in slice. I added some comments also.

```
 hold := make([][]string, 0)
 for _, arr := range arrays {
    isValid := true // Initialy set true
    for _, f := range filterBy {
        if ok := inArray(f, arr); !ok {
            isValid = false // if any filter string does match then make false and break
            break
        }
    }
    // If all filter string found the isValid is true, then append in slice
    if(isValid){ 
       hold = append(hold, arr)
    }
}
```

Full Code in go playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/bDChscCC38Y)

But efficient solution is

```
filterByMap := make(map[string]bool)
// Create a map for filter slice
for _, a := range filterBy {
    filterByMap[a] = true
}
for _, arr := range arrays {
    cnt := 0 // Initial the counter
    for _, a := range arr {
      if filterByMap[a] {
          cnt++  // Increment the counter if filter string found
      }
    }
    // Check if all filter string found ? Append if yes
    if(cnt >= len(filterBy)){ 
         hold = append(hold, arr)
    }
}
```

Full code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ZkeJ-VIFCWt)

Comment: You're absolutely right--your solution is more efficient, but assumes that each needle appears only once in the haystack. See https://play.golang.org/p/8RsN-mhzYpp for some counterexamples.

Comment: @PaSTE I don't know OP need that aspect also or not, but you are right

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/ledongthuc/goterators that support Some() and Every() that I created to reuse aggregate & transforms functions.
But with your case, I think you will need to combine with Filter() and Exist() this same lib.

[image]

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/ledongthuc/goterators"
)

func main() {
    arrays := [][]string{
        {"some", "value"},
        {"some", "value", "another"},
        {"value", "another", "test"},
        {"value", "test"},
        {"some", "test"},
    }

    expected := []string{"some", "value"}
    filteredItems := goterators.Filter(arrays, func(itemList []string) bool {
        for _, expectedItem := range expected {
            if !goterators.Exist(itemList, expectedItem) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    })

    fmt.Println(filteredItems)
}
```

This lib requires the Go 1.18 to use that support generic + dynamic type you want to use with.